# Find value in stream that is less couple of times then max value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to find first date that is older then actual maximum date one year. I try to do it with streams but I'm stuck.

```
List<String> intervalIdList = new HashSet();

intervalIdList.add("2018-01");
intervalIdList.add("2017-12");
intervalIdList.add("2017-11");
intervalIdList.add("2017-10");
...
intervalIdList.add("2016-12"); // this is the value I want to find

LocalDate localDateSet =
                    intervalIdSet.stream()
                            .map(s-> LocalDate.parse(s))
                            .sorted()
                            .filter(localDate -> localDate < max(localDate)) // something like max(localDate)
                            .findFirst();
```

Am I have to write maximum filtered value to variable outside the stream?

Comment: Are you looking just for the maximum date in the stream?

Comment: "Actual max" ? or the max of stream ?

Comment: I want to find it in one stream then compare it with values to find value that is 12 month earlier

Comment: Can you give an example with values ? this is very unclear

Comment: @azro yes something like "Actual max" I look for

Comment: Actulal max has no sense^^

Comment: You can't, in one read-stream find the max and operate like Filter usig this max, you can't

Comment: Thanks, for the example, bu cant you explain what it is this value tht you need ? 2018-01 is the max, so minus 1 year you have 2017-01, and the max before this date is 2016-12, is that it ?

Comment: @azro yes I want to find values that is less then actual max 12 months so max = 2018-01 and 12 months older is 2016-12, 2016-11 etc.

Comment: `List<String> intervalIdList = new HashSet();` this makes *perfect* sense to begin with...

Comment: stream twice - find max, filter from that max

Comment: "findFirst" and "collect all" you're telling us opposite^^

Comment: @azro exactly the reason I voted to close this...

Answer (score 2):

Seems you're looking for the max of dates 1 year before today:

```
List<String> intervalIdList = new ArrayList<>();

intervalIdList.add("2018-01-01");
intervalIdList.add("2017-12-01");
intervalIdList.add("2017-11-01");
intervalIdList.add("2017-10-01");
intervalIdList.add("2016-12-01"); // this is the value I want to find

LocalDate localDateSet = intervalIdList.stream()
        .map(LocalDate::parse)
        .filter(ld -> ld.isBefore(LocalDate.now().minus(Period.of(1, 0, 0))))
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(LocalDate::toEpochDay))
        .get();

System.out.println(localDateSet);
```

That prints `2016-12-01`

Note that I had to add days to the date strings to match the default format expected by `LocalDate.parse`.

Because of the filter, it's probably safer to explicitly check the optional in order to handle cases of where no values matched the predicate:

```
Optional<LocalDate> max = intervalIdList.stream()
        .map(LocalDate::parse)
        .filter(ld -> ld.isBefore(LocalDate.now().minus(Period.of(1, 0, 0))))
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(LocalDate::toEpochDay));
```

And check before reading the max value:

```
if(max.isPresent()) {
    LocalDate ld = max.get();
}
```

Comment: Yes I do it it that way but I think there is a chance to do it in one stream

Comment: @Adriano This is one stream. Look at the first snippet, which calls `.get()` directly. You may want to change it to `.orElse`...

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the actual latest date like so,

```
LocalDate latestDate = intervalIdList.stream().map(s -> s.split("-"))
        .map(sp -> LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(sp[0]), Integer.parseInt(sp[1]), 1))
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(LocalDate::toEpochDay)).orElse(null);
```

Then we need to find all the dates which are one year older than the latest date, and then get the latest date of them. So this code would do that.

```
LocalDate firstDateOneYearOlder = intervalIdList.stream().map(s -> s.split("-"))
        .map(sp -> LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(sp[0]), Integer.parseInt(sp[1]), 1))
        .filter(d -> ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d, latestDate) > 365)
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(LocalDate::toEpochDay)).orElse(null);
```

Also notice this solution uses your original input data `List` in the same format without any modifications.